# What is the theoretical period of BCryptGenRandom function?

Tags: c, cryptography, bcrypt

I'm trying to use the function `BCryptGenRandom` defined in the `bcrypt.h` header file. However, I cannot find information about the security properties of this function.

What is the theoretical period of `BCryptGenRandom` function?

MSDN does not seem to provide this information.

Comment: It does not have a period because it does not produce a periodic sequence.

Comment: @JamesKPolk That's not entirely correct. It does likely  have an internal state, and if the internal state repeats you would get a so called cycle, which would be close to a "period" (but different initial states may produce cycles of different sizes). However, generally cycles are *very* large and the RNG may include reseeding.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, *if* it never reseeded then it would be periodic. But it does reseed, at least if it implements CTR-DRBG like it says it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft :

> The default random number provider implements an algorithm for
> generating random numbers that complies with the [NIST SP800-90](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-90a.pdf)
> standard, specifically the CTR_DRBG portion of that standard.

NIST :

> The seed used to instantiate the DRBG must contain sufficient entropy
> to provide an assurance of randomness. If the seed is kept secret, and
> the algorithm is well designed, the bits output by the DRBG will be
> unpredictable, up to the instantiated security strength of the DRBG.
>
> CTR_DRBG uses an approved block cipher algorithm in the counter mode

We expect maximum number of bits output from CTR_DRBG is equal to the 2^blocksize.  Interestingly, [Campagna](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/379.pdf) shows that we cannot distinguish the output of CTR_DRBG from a true random number generator

> The NIST codebook-based deterministic random bit generators are
> analyzed in the context of being indistinguishable from random. Upper
> and lower bounds based on the probability of distinguishing the output
> are proven. These bounds imply that the security of the designs are
> bounded by the codebook width, or more precisely on the property that
> the codebooks act like a random permutation, as opposed to their
> underlying security parameter or key length. This paper concludes that
> these designs fail to support security parameters larger than the
> codebook width.